# Can I use an outdoor 8/3 wire to hookup lights outdoor?

Tags: electrical

I have removed a hot tub from my house and want to know if I can use the cable for some outdoor lights.  The wire is a **8 gauge 3 wire** hooked up to a **double pole 50 Amp breaker**.  It is a lot of wire and rated for outdoor use.  What is the best course of action.  [image: The wire]

Comment: i know the wire is fine, I checked the cover and all is fine.  i guess my question is what is the best way to take what i have and make it usable for a few lights and a plug.  This will all be done outdoors.

Comment: Feel free to update the question title to better reflect the actual question.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the cable to feed a small sub-panel. Then you can feed your new circuits from that. This gives you a lot of flexibility.

Where was the hot tub? Where is this cable exactly?

Comment: That would be great, but the install is outdoors.  not to sure if they have outdoor power panels for Canada.

Comment: I'm sure they do. Can you being the cable just inside the house/basement?

Comment: the line leaves the main breaker panel and travels inside the house 3 feet before leaving the house.  I did find an outdoor panel that may work. [link] (https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.48-circuit-125a-240v-outdoor-loadcentre.1000171698.html)

Answer (score 2):

As long as the cable is in good condition, there's no problem with using it.  However, using 8 AWG cable to feed general lighting, will be troublesome.

You could use it to supply a panel, which in turn could be used to supply the lighting.